# How to protect child app urls using auth in a Django DRF API

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

This is my scenario:

I have a legacy db and an Django api that is using it. Now we are developing another package with Django DRF that will be installed in the 'parent' app.

The parent app already have oauth authentication.

So in the parent app's **settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',)
}
```

Then the routes are protected under this auth system. This is **routes.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include('myapp.routes', namespace='api')),
    # OAuth 2.0
    path('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider'))
]
```

I install my package, that basically is a DRF API with managed=False models, and it will be an API that will work against the legacy DB. (this is done and working ok)

```
pip install -m my_new_child_package
```

After I install the package and add it's urls I would like to have authentication as well. Basically apply same auth of the parent app.
So I am going to have this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include('myapp.routes', namespace='api')),
    path('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider'))

    # I want to protect routes under api/v2/ as well with existent auth system.
    path('api/v2/', include('my_new_child_package.urls')),
]
```

Should I configure something in my child app, or can what other alternative do I have? A middleware?

Comment: That should be enough. Maybe check if the new package's views are explicitly using their own auth classes?

Comment: @BrianD No, it is not working straight away. We are not using any sort of auth in the child package.